# How to express any element of half open intervals of the form $(a,b]$ as the union or intersection of open intervals of the form $(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Let the following be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ $\mathcal{A}_{1}=\{(a,b) : a<b\}$ and $\mathcal{A}_{2}=\{(a,b] : a<b\}$. Show that any element of $\mathcal{A}_{1}$ can be expressed as a countable union or intersection of elements of $\mathcal{A}_{2}$ and vice versa.

This seems fairly straightforward except in the case of expressing $b \in \mathcal{A}_{2} $ as a countable union or intersection of elements of $\mathcal{A}_{1}$, I don't think it's possible with unions because for $b$ to be equal to the union surely it would have to be in the union hence it wouldn't be a union of elements of $\mathcal{A}_{1}$ and I can't think of anyway it could be done with intersection, my best guess is that I have to use some kind of trickery with limits but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: $(a,b]=\bigcap_n(a,b+\frac1n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that it cannot be done with unions, basically for the reason you mentioned. Another way to note this is that unions of open sets are open, open intervals are open, and the given interval is not (why?).

For the intersection, as the commenter noted you can take 
$$
\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(a,b+1/n)=(a,b]
$$
And there is indeed some limit trickery in why any number larger than $b$ is eventually not in one of the intervals in the intersection on the left (and thus not in the intersection of all of them), however $b$ is in every one of the intervals intersected.